# Do you have to manually close boost::asio sockets if they are members of a shared_ptr object?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a socket that's a member of a shared_ptr object. Do I have to explicitly call `socket.close()` or is it safe to assume that it is closed automatically?

The reason I ask is because in this [TCP Daytime Server Example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) the author doesn't explicitly call `socket.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you need the socket to be closed.

In general, the socket desctructor causes the socket to close (because not doing so would amount to a resource leak).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you